# how to install application in iphone

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. i develop a small application in snow leopard. now i want to check in iphone. hiw can i install it in iphone. Is there any necessity of generate  .apk file or .exe files. pls post any link about this information thank u.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must pay the $99/year fee to be a registered developer first. Follow [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2).